# Atom header files c++

Tags: c++, header, include

I am new at c++ and coding in general and I would appreciate your help! So I am using Atom and when I am trying to include a header file in my source program, it doesn't seem to recognize it. Here is a very simple program I am trying to run:

My source file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "file.h"
using namespace std;

int main() {
  opa();

  return 0;
}
```

My header file(file.h):

```
#ifndef FILE_H_
#define FILE_H_

void opa() {
  cout << "Numerai" << endl;
}

#endif
```

The error I get when I compile it says: 'opa' was not declared in this scope. Any idea what is the mistake?

Comment: That's weird. Either the compiler cannot find `file.h`, but then it would complain about this on the `#include` line, or it can find it, but then it shouldn't complain about the function. Maybe try a less generic name than "file.h"?

Comment: The shown code is obviously not the real code you're trying to compile, but fake code. If this is exactly what's being compiled, the error message will be very different. The real error message should be "error: ‘cout’ was not declared in this scope" Please show real code,  instead of fake code. The only thing that fake code will give you is fake answers.

Comment: I still get an error.

Comment: file.h  can present on some platform, e.g. on windows. you included wrong file

Comment: I made the name of the header file less generic, as Angew suggested, and now I get the error Sam said.

Comment: Then all that's left is to use `std::cout` and `std::endl` in file.h.

Comment: I get the same error.

Comment: @user9851117 Move `#include <iostream>` from your source file to `file.h`.

Comment: I get the same result :(

Answer (score 0):

Order of file search for meta-command

```
#include "file.h"
```

would be

- user-defined include locations
- default platform locations
- local folder (same as source file)

if user didn't provide  location for include files, compiler may take a platform-specific "file.h".

Comment: The files are in the same folder and if I write the whole path instead of the file name in the #include, I get the same error.